# This version of OSX is not able to perform the necessary dSYM transformations

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline

```
[31merror: could not complete submission of dSYM at /Users/XXUSERXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-flcoueeibbfifebpxptgzctdsqel/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ProjectNameAlpha/BuildProductsPath/ProjectNameAlpha-iphoneos/ProjectName.app.dSYM: 

Error Domain=com.crashlytics.mac.error-domain.process-dsym Code=4 "This version of OSX is not able to perform the necessary dSYM transformations." 
UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=This version of OSX is not able to perform the necessary dSYM transformations.}
[0m Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

    ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
```

I'm getting the above error message when I upgraded my MAC Mini (Catalina) latest (16 GB RAM) and XCode to latest version. 
I'm working with Jenkins to run test cases for IOS and ones test cases are generated then it will get uploaded to Sonar Qube server.
Things Which I've tired.
Restarting MAC mini, Closed XCode, Checked XCode configuration like "Debug information format" set to Yes,"Debug information format" to "DWARF with dSYM file".

Earlier it was working fine after update it is not generating the build, Fastlane is not installed.

Thanks

Comment: The Error message I was getting is because of Mac OSX update.. 
I've updated MacBook Pro from Sierra to Catalina, and that's were things got complicated.
I tired with different system which is running Sierra and it worked, again just to make sure it was happening because of the update, I've updated my other Mac Book Pro also and got the same error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Updated:** (16th Nov 2020 onwards)

Remove older `pod 'Fabric' & pod 'Crashlytics'` from Podfile. Add following dependencies.

```
# Add the pod for Firebase Crashlytics
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'

# Recommended: Add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
```

**Older :**

Please check whether you are using latest Crashlytics & Fabric library.

```
pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.10.2'
pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.14.0'
```

**Next Step:**

- update your podfile with these pods
- Then run `pod install`

Now, build the project, it should work.

Answer (score 21):

Your version of the Fabric pod is not able to handle symbols from the latest version of MacOS. You'll want to update to the latest pod version (1.10.2 as of 10/21/2019). You may need to `sudo gem install cocoapods`, `pod repo update`, `pod cache clean`, target the newer versions in your Podfile (see next paragraph), and `pod update`.

I had v1.9.0 of the pod and was getting the same error. I had to target '~> 1.10' specifically or it wouldn't update. Since my project also includes the Crashlytics pod, I had to update that one as well ('~> 3.14', specifically).

Build, profit. Best of luck!

Comment: I tired that but I don't have the access to the pod, I can't change the version, so what I did is replaced the old with new machine and started setting up from scratch. I thought about resetting my old Mac machine but the thing is I can't cause lot of work is going on that machine so instead I changed it. That worked for me..!! Anyways I tried your answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Faced the same error with xamarin ios project. So looks like reason not in pod version.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I did to make the **upload-symbols** tool work:

In my **Podfile**, removed the version limit for Fabric and Crashlytics.

Mine was as follows:

```
  pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.7.13'
  pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.10.7'
```

And I changed it to:

```
  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'Crashlytics'
```

I then executed **pod install** and then the script was able to function.