# com.crashlytics.mac.error-domain.process-dsym Code=4 "This version of OSX is not able to perform the necessary dSYM transformations

Tags: ios, objective-c

I tried multiple time however no luck getting ...pls help me

Using Xcode 10.1  and Objective c

Thanks in advance

I put in script

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run"

echo "UPLOADING DSYM FILE ON FIREBASE CONSOLSE"

INFO_PLIST="$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$INFOPLIST_PATH"

if [ -f "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$INFOPLIST_PATH" ] ; then
ENVIRONMENT_NAME=`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :EnvironmentName" "$INFO_PLIST"`

if [ "$ENVIRONMENT_NAME" = "PROD" ] || [ "$ENVIRONMENT_NAME" = "prod" ]; then
echo "PROD CONFIGURATION"
"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/upload-symbols" -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/DBS/SupportingFiles/Production/ProdGoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"

elif [ "$ENVIRONMENT_NAME" = "UAT" ] || [ "$ENVIRONMENT_NAME" = "uat" ]; then
echo "UAT CONFIGURATION"
"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/upload-symbols" -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/DBS/SupportingFiles/UAT/UATGoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"

else
echo "DEV CONFIGURATION"
"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/upload-symbols" -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/DBS/SupportingFiles/SITUAT/SITUATGoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
fi

fi
```

Getting error while running in device

```
[31merror: could not complete submission of dSYM at /Users/XXUSERXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-flcoueeibbfifebpxptgzctdsqel/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ProjectNameAlpha/BuildProductsPath/ProjectNameAlpha-iphoneos/ProjectName.app.dSYM: 

Error Domain=com.crashlytics.mac.error-domain.process-dsym Code=4 "This version of OSX is not able to perform the necessary dSYM transformations." 
UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=This version of OSX is not able to perform the necessary dSYM transformations.}
[0m Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Answer (score 0):

> This version of OSX is not able to perform the necessary dSYM transformations.

You got your answer basically. Is it an old project? You should update at least the mac os to a newer version and try again. xCode 10 is old, too.

On the other hand, crashlytics is bought up by Google and now called Firebase Crashlytics. It has a new version 4.0.0 (Not beta), so I suggest to install that pod if it is possible. Fabric service has been shut down completely since April of 2020.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started

Comment: I followed below link but no luck

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58408244/this-version-of-osx-is-not-able-to-perform-the-necessary-dsym-transformations

Comment: What is your mac os version?

Comment: macOS Catalina
version 10.15.3

Comment: Yeah, in this case I am 100% sure that your problem is that your crashlytics pod version is too old and mac OS changed so much since then that the old pods scripts fails to run. Try updating the Crashlytics as I suggested in the answer. You should be able too even if you are using xCode 10